# Using VBO/IBOs to draw a large graph

Tags: c#, opengl, vbo, opentk

I'm trying to draw a large graph (~3,000,000 vertices, ~5,000,000 edges) using OpenTK.

However I can't seem to get it working.

I creating a VBO containing the positions of all the vertices like so

```
// build the coords list
float[] coords = new float[vertices.Length * 3];
Dictionary<int, int> vertexIndexMap = new Dictioanry<int, int>();
int count = 0, i = 0;
foreach (Vertex v in vertices) {
    vertexIndexMap[v.Id] = i++;
    coords[count++] = v.x;
    coords[count++] = v.y;
    coords[count++] = v.z;
}

// build the index list
int[] indices = new int[edges.Length * 2];
count = 0;
foreach (Edge e in edges) {
    indices[count++] = vertexIndexMap[e.First.Id];
    indices[count++] = vertexIndexMap[e.Second.Id];
}

// bind the buffers
int[] bufferPtrs = new int[2];
GL.GenBuffers(2, bufferPtrs);

GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.IndexArray);

// buffer the vertex data
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, bufferPtrs[0]);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(coords.Length * sizeof(float)), coords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero); // tell opengl we have a closely packed vertex array
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

// buffer the index data
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, bufferPtrs[1]);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(indices.Length * sizeof(int)), indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);
```

And I attempt to draw the buffers like so:

```
// draw the vertices
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, bufferPtrs[0]);
GL.Color3(Color.Blue);
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Points, 0, coords.Length);

// draw the edges
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, bufferPtrs[1]);
GL.Color3(Color.Red);
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Lines, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, bufferPtrs[1]);
```

When I run this, all of the vertices draw as expected in all of their correct locations,
However about half of the edges are drawn joining a vertex to the origin.

To sanity check I tried drawing the edges with a Begin/End block, and they all drew correctly.

Could someone please point out how am I misusing the VBOs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last argument to your `DrawElements()` call is wrong:

```
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Lines, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt,
                bufferPtrs[1]);
```

Without an element array buffer bund, the last argument to `DrawElements()` is a pointer to the indices. If an element array buffer is bound (which is the case in your code), the last argument is an offset into the buffer. To use the whole buffer, the offset is 0:

```
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Lines, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
```

You probably also want to remove this call:

```
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.IndexArray);
```

This is not for enabling vertex indices, but for color indices. This would be for color index mode, which is a very obsolete feature.

Comment: wow, that was all that was wrong. I missed that in the doco! thanks heaps. And thanks for pointing out about the IndexArray.